# How can I keep synced two React states?

Tags: reactjs

I have in the next code, two `useState` that comes from above that I want to keep them synced in lower components.

```js
function ChildComponent({langSrc1, langSrc2}) {
  // Here I need to keep langSrc1 and langSrc2 in sync

  return <h1>{langSrc1}</h1>
}

function ParentComponent() {
  const [langSrc1, setLangSrc1] = React.useState('hello');
  const [langSrc2, setLangSrc2] = React.useState('world');
  
  return <ChildComponent langSrc1={langSrc1} langSrc2={langSrc2} />
}

function App() {
  return <ParentComponent />
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: They are in sync

Comment: What do you mean by `sync`?

Comment: Do you mean besides passing `setLangSrc1` and `setLangSrc2` and calling them both with the same arguments? I'm not sure why you'd what to have two state models with exactly the same value...

Comment: The example is very generic, states actually comes from two independent components from above, but in the child I need to connect them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat `React.useEffect` like a listener over your state variables. Keeping this in mind you just use a temporary variable to store a common value and next is simple logic to follow. To have that common value unchanged during re-renders of component, I suggest using `React.useRef` - its value is stored and during the whole life of the application.

```js
function ChildComponent({langSrc1, setLangSrc1, langSrc2, setLangSrc2}) {
  const commonLangSrc = React.useRef(langSrc1);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(commonLangSrc.current !== langSrc1) {
      commonLangSrc.current = langSrc1
      setLangSrc2(langSrc1);
    }
    
    if(commonLangSrc.current !== langSrc2) {
      commonLangSrc.current = langSrc2
      setLangSrc1(langSrc2);
    }
    
  }, [langSrc1, langSrc2]);

  return <h1>src1: {langSrc1} src2: {langSrc2}</h1>
}

function ParentComponent() {
  const [langSrc1, setLangSrc1] = React.useState('hello');
  const [langSrc2, setLangSrc2] = React.useState('world');
  
  // Trigger Changes on interval
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setLangSrc1('world');
    }, 2000);
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      setInterval(() => {
        setLangSrc2('hello');
      }, 2000);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  
  return <ChildComponent
    langSrc1={langSrc1}
    setLangSrc1={setLangSrc1}
    langSrc2={langSrc2}
    setLangSrc2={setLangSrc2}
  />
}

function App() {
  return <ParentComponent />
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Just press **Run code snippet** above.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Weird that no one asked this before, thank you!